# Compare the two data-frames columns on the basis of id's in the dataframe

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, numpy

I am totally new to python . I have two data-frames which are of the same dataset but one is input and one is the output.

So, Here is my input dataframe

```
Document_ID OFFSET  PredictedFeature
    0         0            2000
    0         8            2000
    0         16           2200
    0         23           2200
    0         30           2200
    1          0            2100
    1          5            2100
    1          7            2100
```

SO Here I am giving this as an input to my `ml-model`. It gives me an output in the this format only .

Now my output looks like ,

```
  Document_ID    OFFSET   PredictedFeature
        0         0            2000
        0         8            2000
        0         16           2100
        0         23           2100
        0         30           2200
        1          0           2000
        1          5           2000
        1          7           2100
```

Now, In this two data-frames what I am trying to do is that

for that Id, for that OFFSET the input feature is same as that of output feature . if It is then I want to add true  as a value in the new column if it is not then it will add false value.

Now, If we see in the example data

```
for ID 0 , for offset 16 the input feature is 2200 and output feature is 2100 so it is a false.
```

Can any one please help me with this ? Any thing will be helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If there are same index values between both `DataFrame`s and also same values in first 2 columns use:

```
inputdf['new'] = inputdf['PredictedFeature'] == outputdf['PredictedFeature']
```

Comment: A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame.
Try using .loc[row_indexer,col_indexer] = value instead   .So I am getting this error

Comment: @ganeshkaspate - Can you check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20625582/how-to-deal-with-settingwithcopywarning-in-pandas) ?

Comment: Is there any way though which I will come to know that  if I have 50 records of 2100 in input csv then out of that if 25 has matched  ?

Comment: @ganeshkaspate - hmm, so solution failed? Or you ask for something else?

Comment: could you please let me know is there any way ?

Comment: @ganeshkaspate - Can you explain more? Maybe the best is create some sample data with expected ouput - [how to provide a great pandas example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples)

Comment: Or Else I will put another question and will add it in comments

Comment: Added this question please check 
   https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58426376/get-the-count-of-matching-and-not-matching-columns-data-in-a-dataframe

Answer (score 0):

concat

```
>>> df = pd.concat([df1, df2])
>>> df = df.reset_index(drop=True)
```

group by

```
 >>> df_gpby = df.groupby(list(df.columns))
```

get index of unique records

```
>>> idx = [x[0] for x in df_gpby.groups.values() if len(x) == 1]
```

filter

```
>>> df.reindex(idx)
         Date   Fruit   Num   Color
9  2013-11-25  Orange   8.6  Orange
8  2013-11-25   Apple  22.1     Red
```

use this method you can find out the different datas by index value, you can add new column for this index value only false another values are true

Comment: Yes It says true .

Comment: Sorry,I have done a bit wrong here when I did the compare as you gave the earlier solution it is saying false