# Get the count of matching and not matching columns data in a dataframe

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, numpy

I have two dataframes  which are like,
This is the input csv data .

```
Document_ID OFFSET  PredictedFeature
    0         0            2000
    0         8            2000
    0         16           2200
    0         23           2200
    0         30           2200
    1          0            2100
    1          5            2100
    1          7            2100
```

Now I have the output data as well

```
 Document_ID    OFFSET   PredictedFeature
        0         0            2000
        0         8            2100
        0         16           2100
        0         23           2100
        0         30           2200
        1          0           2000
        1          5           2000
        1          7           2100
```

Now, Here what I am trying to do is that matching the results weather they are getting or not.

So I did ,

```
df1_inputPredictedFeature_column['new'] = df1_inputPredictedFeature_column['PredictedFeature'] == df1_predictedFeature_column['PredictedFeature']
```

This adds one columns which will tell weather it is matching the predictedfeature column or not.

Now what I am trying is ,

there are a total of 2 features where 2000 is in the predictedfeature of input csv. But in the output csv only first place it is matching and not in the second place.

SO I am trying to get this data like ,

```
predictedFeatureClass  inputCsvOccured   outputcsvmatched  

 2000                        2                1

2200                         3                 1
```

SO, How will I get this data ? any help will be great.

Answer (score 0):

One idea is convert `new` column to integers by [`Series.view`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.view.html) and then aggregate column `new` with `size` and `sum` by list of tuples for specify new columns names:

```
df1['new'] = (df1['PredictedFeature'] == df2['PredictedFeature']).view('i1')

df = (df1.groupby("PredictedFeature")['new']
         .agg([('inputCsvOccured','size'), ('outputcsvmatched','sum')])
         .reset_index())
print (df)
   PredictedFeature  inputCsvOccured  outputcsvmatched
0              2000                2                 1
1              2100                3                 1
2              2200                3                 1
```

Pandas 0.25+ solution:

```
df1['new'] = (df1['PredictedFeature'] == df2['PredictedFeature']).view('i1')

df = (df1.groupby("PredictedFeature")
         .agg(inputCsvOccured=pd.NamedAgg(column='new', aggfunc='size'),
              outputcsvmatched=pd.NamedAgg(column='new', aggfunc='sum'))
         .reset_index())
```

Answer (score 0):

you can do it using groupby like below

```py
df1_inputPredictedFeature_column = pd.DataFrame([['0', '0', '2000'], ['0', '8', '2000'], ['0', '16', '2200'], ['0', '23', '2200'], ['0', '30', '2200'], ['1', '0', '2100'], ['1', '5', '2100'], ['1', '7', '2100']], columns=('Document_ID', 'OFFSET', 'PredictedFeature'))
df1_predictedFeature_column = pd.DataFrame([['0', '0', '2000'], ['0', '8', '2100'], ['0', '16', '2100'], ['0', '23', '2100'], ['0', '30', '2200'], ['1', '0', '2000'], ['1', '5', '2000'], ['1', '7', '2100']], columns=('Document_ID', 'OFFSET', 'PredictedFeature'))

df1_inputPredictedFeature_column['new'] = (df1_inputPredictedFeature_column['PredictedFeature'] == df1_predictedFeature_column['PredictedFeature']).astype(np.int)

result = df1_inputPredictedFeature_column.groupby("PredictedFeature").agg({"PredictedFeature":"count", "new":np.sum})

result.columns = ["inputCsvOccured", "outputcsvmatched"]
result.index.name = "predictedFeatureClass"

result.reset_index(inplace=True)
print(result)
```

**Result**

```
predictedFeatureClass  inputCsvOccured  outputcsvmatched
0                  2000                2                 1
1                  2100                3                 1
2                  2200                3                 1
```

Comment: I think it is giving the exact output , I think its taking the same dataframe

Comment: Please not change solution by my answer.